# Get DOM of Google Maps API InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polymer, infowindow

If I create an `InfoWindow` like this

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( {content: '<place-panel></place-panel>'} );
```

, where `<place-panel>` is a custom WebComponent created with Polymer, how can I access the DOM-tree of the `InfoWindow` so that I can manipulate my `<place-panel>`?

Simply using `infoWindow.getContent()` doesn't work, I get

```
infoWindow.getContent(...).querySelector is not a function
```

when doing so. Trying to use

```
{content: document.createElement('<place-panel></place-panel>')}
```

when creating the InfoWindow results in

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': 
  The tag name provided ('<place-panel></place-panel>') is not a valid name.
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue and also explain what you want to *manipulate* (and how) in the InfoWindow content.

Comment: createElement should be like this `document.createElement('place-panel')`